# Does satellite imagery have a unique azimuth for each of its spectral bands?

Tags: remote-sensing

Does satellite imagery have a unique azimuth for each of its spectral bands?

Is it right to say that if a sensor has 8 spectral bands, then it may have 8 different azimuth angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on satellite, but most of them have one or two sensors with the same angle of view. For example, Landsat 8 has 2 sensors, TIRS (2 bands) and OLI (9 bands). All of bands have the same angle while sensing. Figuratively speaking - you can not sense Africa with 4 OLI bands and at the same time sense Europe with other 5 bands.